# How to restore .bak only if it's good

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm using Tsql script to restore several databases.

```
RESTORE DATABASE XXX_M
   FROM DISK = 'C:\XXX.bak'
   WITH FILE = 1, replace
GO
```

Sometimes the .bak file comes corrupted (not data corrupted ).

I want to know if there is a way to check if the file is not corrupted then restore else don't.
I've tried to use @@rowcount after restore VERIFYONLY but it's not good.

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY 
   FROM DISK = 'C:\xxx.bak'
if @@ROWCOUNT !=0
print 'false'
else 
print 'good'
```

Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This is why you test your backups... that, ultimately, is the best test. If it's happening frequently shouldn't you check your storage?

Comment: What if you have 2,000 backups? will you test every one of them every day?
It's happening not that frequently but still, I want to prevent from the database to restore unsuccessfully and been stuck on a single user.

Comment: If you have 2,000 backups you should be able to automate testing restores pretty easily. You're not managing *taking* those backups manually, right? You don't necessarily have to test all 2,000 every night, but you could rotate so that every database is checked with a real restore every n days. There is no value in taking backups if you can't be certain they can be restored.

Comment: The problem was not with testing backups, the backups are been restored every day.
The problem was when the file transfer interrupted then the file (zip) is not complete.
Thanks for the answers the script is good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking `@@ROWCOUNT` isn't valuable here because `RESTORE VERIFONLY` doesn't return any results. It either prints status messages or error messages. So, a simple `TRY`/`CATCH` should do:

```
BEGIN TRY
  RESTORE VERIFYONLY ...
  RESTORE DATABASE   ...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH
```

If the `VERIFYONLY` fails, it will raise an exception, and skip the `RESTORE`.

Of course, there are still going to be scenarios where `VERIFYONLY` will succeed but the `RESTORE` will fail (for example, something swoops in and takes all your disk space).